to Implement Incremental Load for Recent Data in dbt using multiple is_incremental conditions in one dbt model
I'm looking to implement an incremental loading strategy in dbt where I only fetch data from the past few days from my source tables before performing a join to create the final table. I want to avoid pulling all data unless it's a full load. I have created similar model as below is this the correct approach?
If this question has already been answered, I would appreciate any links to the relevant discussions.
with cte_a as (
    select col1, col2, current_timestamp() as date_updated 
    from tbl1 
    {% if is_incremental() %}
    where lastupdated = current_timestamp()
    {% endif %}
),

cte_b as (
    select c1, c2 
    from t2
    {% if is_incremental() %}
    where lastupdated = current_timestamp()
    {% endif %}
)

select cte_b.c1, cte_b.c2, cte_a.col1, cte_a.col2, cte_a.date_updated 
from cte_a 
join cte_b on cte_a.col1 = cte_b.c1 
{% if is_incremental() %}
where cte_a.date_updated >= (select max(date_updated) from {{ this }})
{% endif %}

